# La commare secca

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Why is the movie La commare secca (Bertolucci, 1962), not La comare secca (1x m)? I see it translated into English as "The Grim Reaper", is that a standard meaning in some Italian variety for La commare secca? Or is it just a poetic new creation?

Answer (score 2):

TL; DR: the title is not in Italian, rather in Romanesco.

The title of this movie is a reference to the sonnet [*Er tisic*o](https://it.wikisource.org/wiki/Er_tisico) by [Giuseppe Gioacchino Belli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giuseppe_Gioachino_Belli), which is also referred to in the last scene of the movie.

The reason of the different spelling is that Belli did not write poetry in Italian, but rather in [Romanesco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanesco_dialect) (the regional language around Rome). For various historical reasons, Romanesco is very similar to standard Italian but it is not quite identical. In particular it often tends to have a lot more geminate consonants, as in this case.

Comment: Side note: A more recent example of Romanesco is the pair of Netflix series by [Zerocalcare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zerocalcare), which are almost integrally in a mix of Romanesco and Italian. By and large the similarity means they are understandable to most Italians, but I know several people that needed subtitles, and even I have trouble following it from time to time...